# Run script after windows store app has been installed

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

Is there any way to run some activity after a Windows Store app has been installed?

I'd like to get some data from a webservice (data is rarely changes), but I would not like to make the query on the first start, because it might take some time, and I don't want to ruin the user experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can have it run on a separate background thread while concurrently running the main thread. You can allocate limited resources to this separate background thread, then have it subside on it's own.

You can do an async operation as well from your app, see link from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx#AsyncOps

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.  My understanding is that background threads are starting when the application is running.

Comment: Sadly this is the only way you can do this. The only time you can execute code is when your application is running. You can set it up to only run once at the first launch of your application as @AmitApollo suggests, but thats the best approach you've got for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

My codeSHOW app loads data asynchronously when it first starts, and stores the async promise as an app level variable so anything else in the app can await it. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but if it helps, it's available at http://codeshow.codeplex.com.